# In Clojure, how to group elements?

Tags: clojure, group-by, aggregate-functions

In clojure, I want to aggregate this data:

```
(def data [[:morning :pear][:morning :mango][:evening :mango][:evening :pear]])
(group-by first data)
;{:morning [[:morning :pear][:morning :mango]],:evening [[:evening :mango][:evening :pear]]}
```

My problem is that `:evening` and `:morning` are redundant. 
Instead, I would like to create the following collection:

```
([:morning (:pear :mango)] [:evening (:mango :pear)])
```

I came up with:

```
(for [[moment moment-fruit-vec] (group-by first data)] [moment (map second moment-fruit-vec)])
```

Is there a more **idiomatic** solution?

Comment: The variable name in your proposed solution is misleading. The value destructured as 'fruit' is actually a sequence of moment-fruit pair vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come across similar grouping problems. Usually I end up plugging merge-with or update-in into some seq processing step:

```
(apply merge-with list (map (partial apply hash-map) data))
```

You get a map, but this is just a seq of key-value pairs:

```
user> (apply merge-with list (map (partial apply hash-map) data))
{:morning (:pear :mango), :evening (:mango :pear)}
user> (seq *1)
([:morning (:pear :mango)] [:evening (:mango :pear)])
```

This solution only gets what you want if each key appears twice, however. This might be better:

```
(reduce (fn [map [x y]] (update-in map [x] #(cons y %))) {} data)
```

Both of these feel "more functional" but also feel a little convoluted. Don't be too quick to dismiss your solution, it's easy-to-understand and functional enough.

Comment: What do you think of `(apply merge-with (comp flatten list) (map (partial apply hash-map) data))`?

Comment: That's a good, concise fix. I believe `flatten` is **O(n)**, so it might not work well repeatedly applying it in certain datasets.

Comment: You're right. I found a better solution, see my answer. BTW is there any built-in function that does the same as `agg`?

Answer (score 4):

Don't be too quick to dismiss `group-by`, it has aggregated your data by the desired key and *it hasn't changed the data*. Any other function expecting a sequence of moment-fruit pairs will accept any value looked up in the map returned by `group-by`.

In terms of computing the summary my inclination was to reach for `merge-with` but for that I had to transform the input data into a sequence of maps and construct a "base-map" with the required keys and empty-vectors as values.

```
(let [i-maps (for [[moment fruit] data] {moment fruit})
      base-map (into {} 
                  (for [key (into #{} (map first data))] 
                    [key []]))]
      (apply merge-with conj base-map i-maps))

{:morning [:pear :mango], :evening [:mango :pear]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Meditating on [@mike t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266581/mike-t)'s answer, I've come up with:

```
(defn agg[x y] (if (coll? x) (cons y x) (list y x)))
(apply merge-with agg (map (partial apply hash-map) data))
```

This solution works also when the keys appear more than twice on `data`:

```
 (apply merge-with agg (map (partial apply hash-map) 
     [[:morning :pear][:morning :mango][:evening :mango] [:evening :pear] [:evening :kiwi]]))
;{:morning (:mango :pear), :evening (:kiwi :pear :mango)}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe just modify the standard group-by a little bit:

```
(defn my-group-by 
  [fk fv coll]  
  (persistent!
   (reduce
    (fn [ret x]
      (let [k (fk x)]
        (assoc! ret k (conj (get ret k []) (fv x)))))
    (transient {}) coll)))
```

then use it as:

```
(my-group-by first second data)
```